# Better way to make a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

My following Code:

```
this.selectedMonths = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedMonths));
```

After this code, this.selectedMonths will be read as a properly formatted JSON object.

My question is if there is any better way? Having to do JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) which is two methods seems quite redundant.

> Side Note: JSON.stringify() on its own won't do the trick because it
>   puts quotation marks on the entire JSON array and that's why I need
>   JSON.parse() to get rid of those quotation marks.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do that at all?

Comment: What is `selectedMonths`? What does it look like?

Comment: @Pointy because I want to make it a JSON object?

Comment: @Andy selectedMonths is an array of strings

Comment: So, you're converting a JS object to a string, then converting it back to a JS object (there's no such thing as a JSON object), which is why @Pointy asked the question. Why bother?

Comment: There's not really any such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a serialization scheme. It's true that not all JavaScript objects can be completely and successfully serialized as JSON, but because you didn't post the original object it's not possible to say anything in particular about it. If it's just an array of strings, as you said in a comment above, then there's no point in the conversion you're doing. A JavaScript array of strings is serializable as JSON as-is.

Comment: I am really interested about what console.log(selectedMonths) looks like. My guess... it is just a JSON

Comment: Finally, removing quotes from a JSON string will make the JSON invalid if that's what you were aiming to do. `JSON.parse` just parses the string back to an object.

Comment: True, what I was referring is to convert an array of strings into a JSON formatted array of objects. Does that make more sense? For example: this.selectedMonths = [{"id":"1","name":"Bob"}, {...}]. I want it to turn into [{"id":1, "name": "Bob"}]. JSON.stringify() would put quotations on the entire array and therefore I have to do JSON.parse() on top of that.

Comment: @Andy, yes so therefore I have to do JSON.stringify() first and then JSON.parse(). I was just curious if I can avoid using two methods

Comment: All it looks like you want is to change the id from a string to an integer. Is that correct?

Comment: From the example, yes. On my actual use case, the array has a few thousand objects so I'll need change certain keys value pairs from string to integers

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments clarifying your issue here's a method that `map`s over the array with a function called `toInteger`. `toInteger` accepts an array of keys that you want to change to integers.

```js
let selectedMonths = [{
  id: "1",
  name: "Bob",
  age: "12"
}, {
  id: "2",
  name: "Harry",
  age: "34"
}];

function toInteger(keys) {
  return function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(obj, key) {
      if (keys.includes(key)) obj[key] = Number(obj[key]);
      return obj;
    }, obj);
  }
}

let out = selectedMonths.map(toInteger(['id', 'age']));

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Downvoter: if you take a look at the comments this is what the OP needs rather than what was specified in the question.

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for because I might as well just go with the original JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) but I do thank you for your time and will give you an upvote to negate whoever given you a downvote

Comment: But [that doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/dkoymam7/). It doesn't remove the quotes from the values that should be integers. This does. @ezzzCash

Comment: Did you look at the jsfiddle in the "But that doesn't work." text? _It doesn't work_. I'm not sure what else to tell you,